# Passing stdout to C program

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork, system

I am trying to figure out piping in C by playing around with it. I want to write a program that takes the output from the shell command 'cat', saves it as a string, then prints that string. The command should look like this:

```
cat foo.txt | ./my_prog
```

I am having issues sending the output from the cat command to my_prog. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pipe_1[2];
    pid_t pid = -1;
    char catString[200];
    catString [199] = '\0';

    // dup stdout to pipe_1
    if( dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, pipe_1[1]) == -1 ){
            perror("Could not create pipe 1");
            exit(-1);
    }

    // fork a new process
    pid = fork();
    switch(pid){
    case -1:
            perror("Fork 1 failed");
            exit(-1);
    case 0: // child
            // close stdin and write stdout to the string
            close(pipe_1[0]);
            write(pipe_1[1], catString, 200);
            break;
    default: // parent
            // wait for child process to finish, close stdout, then print the string
            wait(NULL);
            close(pipe_1[1]);
            printf("Parent recieved %s\n", catString);
            break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

This doesn't print anything and gives me the output:

> Parent recieved

On a side note, am I using the wait() function correctly? I wanted to make sure the child is done writing to catString before the parent process executed.

Comment: If you wish to create a pipe *inside* your program (which is useless in your case) you should call [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) on  `pipe_1` ( which is otherwise useless) before the `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

The shell will send the output of `cat foo.txt` to `stdin` of your program. You don't have to do anything with "pipes" *inside* your program, just accept the input in the way the shell delivers it.